# Animate N-1th button to the position where other buttons removed

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton

```
`

    [self lastbuttonOnToThisPosition:selectedbtn.tag]

    -(int)lastbutt0nToThisPosition:(int)pos
    {
        int p=[array count]-1;
        if((pos) == ([array count]-1))
            return 0;
        for(p=[array count]-1;p>=0;--p)
        {
            UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:p];
            if(![btn isSelected])
            {
                UIButton *Remove=(UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:pos];
                [Remove   removeFromSuperview];
                [btn     setTag:pos];

                [array replaceObjectAtIndex:pos withObject:[array objectAtIndex:p]];
                [array removeObjectAtIndex:p];
                return p;
            }
        }
        return p;

}`
```

I have say for example N UIButtons arranged sequentially, once I select any of them it gets removed. I want to animate the N-1th button to the position where other buttons removed.
Please can anyone suggest me suitable method.

Comment: please specify what code have you written till now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of you didnt provide your code, i am including a sample code. Please make changes according to your need.

If there are 3 buttons and if you are tapping second button, then our method should be

```
-(IBAction)tappedBtn2:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.33f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                     animations:^{
                         [btn2 removeFromSuperview];
                         [btn3 removeFromSuperview];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.33f
                                               delay:0.0f
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                          animations:^{
                                              [btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(btn2.frame.origin.x, btn2.frame.origin.y , btn1.frame.size.width, btn1.frame.size.height)];
                                          }
                                          completion:nil];

                     }];

}
```

If you are using a for loop, then use the below code for obtaining the uibutton with a particular tag for deletion and animation

```
[(UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:tagId] // assuming buttons are added to self.view
```

Comment: This is an excessive number of comments. Take it to Skype if you want to exchange friendly personal talk, please :)